# Java Spring Boot apply configuration for FasterXml Jackson library

Tags: java, spring, jackson

I have Spring Boot project with Maven dependency: com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype

And I want to enable two properties ACCEPT_EMPTY_STRING_AS_NULL_OBJECT and FAIL_ON_READING_DUP_TREE_KEY.

But fail two enable them in two different  ways:
1) application.yml

```
  jackson:
         serialization:
             WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS: false
         deserialization:
              FAIL_ON_READING_DUP_TREE_KEY: true
```

2) Adding them as Configuration Bean

```
@Configuration
public class JacksonConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @PostConstruct
    private void configureObjectMapper() {
        objectMapper.enable(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_EMPTY_STRING_AS_NULL_OBJECT );
        objectMapper.enable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_READING_DUP_TREE_KEY );
    }
}
```

Neither one of this ways gave me desired effect. Could you please advice correct way how to do it?

Comment: How is `objectMapper` created ?

Comment: it is created by Spring framework with creates it and injects the reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create and configure `ObjectMapper` from scratch:

```
@Configuration
public class JacksonConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
        return new ObjectMapper()
                .enable(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_EMPTY_STRING_AS_NULL_OBJECT )
                .enable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_READING_DUP_TREE_KEY );
    }
}
```

Comment: Your response is correct way how to define Spring Bean that will be used globally on app. I actually change my code to this:

@Bean
    public ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
        final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        objectMapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
        objectMapper.disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS);
        objectMapper.enable(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_EMPTY_STRING_AS_NULL_OBJECT);
        objectMapper.enable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_READING_DUP_TREE_KEY);
        return objectMapper;
    }

Comment: Perhaps I miss something, but I want to have null value in Request body properties when user passes empty spring in API and enable Strict JSON and get error on duplicated properties in request body.

This I wanted to achieve with ACCEPT_EMPTY_STRI‌​NG_AS_NULL_OBJECT and FAIL_ON_READING_D‌​UP_TREE_KEY

Comment: Maybe rephrase your question and add an example for others to better understand the issue.

Answer (score 5):

I tried to use two options for FasterXml Jackson:

1. ACCEPT_EMPTY_STRING_AS_NULL_OBJECT to automatically map empty
   strings to null values. And look like it is not working jet
   properly, according to
   https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/1563 So I
   solved problem with  writing custom deserialiser.
2. FAIL_ON_READING_D‌​UP_TREE_KEY to enable Strict JSON validation, but the desired effect I get with JsonParser.Feature.STRICT_DUPLICATE_DETECTION.

So now I end up with two working solutions:

```
 @Bean
    public ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
        final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        objectMapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
        objectMapper.disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS);
        objectMapper.enable(JsonParser.Feature.STRICT_DUPLICATE_DETECTION);
        return objectMapper;
    }
```

and application.yml

```
jackson:
     serialization:
         WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS: false
     parser:
          STRICT_DUPLICATE_DETECTION: true
```

I will use application.yml, of course, to keep configuration compact and in one place.

Thanks to @Michal Foksa I will accept your answer, because it is one of the ways how to configure ObjectMapper properly.

Comment: You can/should use the `ObjectMapperBuilder` additionally some modules like the `JavaTimeModule` will automatically be added if found on the classpath. Any `Module` defined as a bean will be added to the ObjectMapper.